# Help me factor this equation

Tags: equation-solving, factorization

I have the following equation:
$$\frac{2\left(a A_3 r + \frac{1}{2} r^2 a'^2 \right)}{a^2 r^2}=\frac{8 G \pi \rho}{3}-\frac{c^2 k}{a^2}$$

```
(2*(a*Subscript[A, 3]*r + (1/2)*r^2*Derivative[1][a]^2))/(a^2*r^2) ==   (8*G*Pi*\[Rho])/3 - (c^2*k)/a^2
```

I know that $\frac{a'}{a}=H$, so how do I force Mathematica to use this to simplify the equation.  I want this equation to look like:
$$\frac{2 A_3}{a r}+H^2=\frac{8 G \pi \rho}{3}-\frac{c^2 k}{a^2}$$

Comment: Maybe:`FullSimplify[((2*(a*Subscript[A, 3]*r + (1/2)*r^2*
          Derivative[1][a]^2))/(a^2*r^2) == (8*G*Pi*\[Rho])/
      3 - (c^2*k)/a^2) /. Derivative[1][a] -> a*H, 
 Assumptions -> a > 0]`.

Comment: PolynomialReduce can be useful for this. I do not have Mathematica available at the moment to demonstrate, but I believe there are prior MSE threads that show this sort of thing.